# animateAlong function is not defined in Raphael javascript?

Tags: raphael

im trying out raphael js examples from http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php#pagetop.

i took the example of animateAlong and tried, but im getting an error of animateAlong function is not defined.

Also made sure that my code is inside `window.onload`. My Raphaël version 2.0.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been removed from Raphael2. See [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/raphaeljs/animatealong/raphaeljs/W9bA0SkArVY/KnPRKi8uFrsJ) for a possible solution. (Haven't checked it out myself, so your mileage may vary...)