# Raphael 2.0.2 doesn't seem to have the .animateAlong command anymore. Is there an alternative?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to animate an eclipse moving along a path using Raphael v2.0.2. I have found some examples that use the .animateAlong() command but the latest version of Raphael doesn't seem to support it anymore. Can anyone suggest an alternative way of achieving this using Raphael v2.0.2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [animateAlong function is not defined in Raphael javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295371/animatealong-function-is-not-defined-in-raphael-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been raised

[animateAlong function is not defined in Raphael javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295371/animatealong-function-is-not-defined-in-raphael-javascript)

[Here there is an interesting example](http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/anyshapeslider.php) using raphael 2

And look [here](https://github.com/brianblakely/raphael-animate-along/blob/master/raphael-animate-along.js) for some code